# Showing that something is a Borel set

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Say that I have the set $A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[n,n+\frac{1}{n}]$. How do I show that this is a Borel set?

My attempt:
I know that $\sigma(\mathscr{L})=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ where $\mathscr{L}$ is the family of closed sets. Since $\sigma(\mathscr{L})$ has a family $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $A_n:=[n,n+\frac{1}{n}]$, it follows from the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[n,n+\frac{1}{n}]\in\sigma(\mathscr{L})=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Members of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra are Borel sets, hence $A$ is a Borel set.

Comment: Looks good to me. But notice that $[n,1+\frac1n]$ is empty for $n>1$. Is that intended?

Comment: Actually it should have been $1/n^2$, but I guess it would not make a difference since $\emptyset\in\mathscr{A}$ where $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: $A$ is a countable union of closed sets. Closed sets are Borel and a countable union of Borel sets is Borel.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good. Actually what you have proved is that the $F_\delta$ sets are borelian. This follows, as you have showed, nicely from the definition of the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains the open sets of $\mathbb R^n$ under the standard topology.